# File resource should not skip files if a separate file resource exists in the puppet project

Tags: puppet

It seems like puppet does not copy a file which is part of a recursive resource, if there is a separate definition for that file somewhere else. Is there a way to avoid this?

For example this does not work:

```
file { '/tmp/foo':
  ensure => 'directory',
  source  => 'puppet:///modules/foo/foo',
  recurse => true,
}

file { '/tmp/foo/installer/requirements.txt':
  ensure  => present,
  replace => false,
  require => File['/tmp/foo'],
}
```

output:

```
$ ls modules/foo/files/foo/installer/
README.rst  requirements.txt
$ rm -r /tmp/foo ; puppet apply --modulepath modules manifests/site.pp 
notice: /Stage[main]//File[/tmp/foo]/ensure: created
notice: /File[/tmp/foo/installer]/ensure: created
notice: /File[/tmp/foo/installer/README.rst]/ensure: defined content as '{md5}c25f2f6d9c3254bab1fd8ae5e4384888'
notice: /Stage[main]//File[/tmp/foo/installer/requirements.txt]/ensure: created
notice: Finished catalog run in 0.05 seconds
```

So the `requirements.txt` file is not copied as part of the first step, but an empty file is created as part of the second step. But I want that file to be copied in the first step and the second step to be skipped, because the file already exists and replace is set to false.

The reason this is a problem is I use `python::virtualenv` and the requirements.txt file I use is copied as part of a recursive file resource.

```
file { '/tmp/foo':
  ensure => 'directory',
  source  => 'puppet:///modules/foo/foo',
  recurse => true,
}

python::virtualenv { '/tmp/python-virtualenv':
  ensure       => present,
  requirements => '/tmp/foo/installer/requirements.txt',
  require      => File['/tmp/foo'],
  ....
```

In the [requirements module](https://github.com/stankevich/puppet-python/blob/1.7.5/manifests/requirements.pp) (used by the [virtualenv module](https://github.com/stankevich/puppet-python/blob/1.7.5/manifests/virtualenv.pp)) a file definition is used like this:

```
if !defined(File[$requirements]) {
  file { $requirements:
    ensure => present,
    ....
    replace => false,
    content => '# Puppet will install and/or update pip packages listed here',
  }
}
```

Because I do not define `File[$requirements]` in my project, it will be defined here, and my version of that file will not be copied.

In case it is important, I use puppet 2.7.23 on Debian 7.

Comment: Just after posting I noticed there is a [bug report](https://github.com/stankevich/puppet-python/issues/64) describing exactly this problem in the python::virtualenv module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there does not seem a solution, I'll add two workarounds;

The first is also mentioned in the [python::virtualenv ticket](https://github.com/stankevich/puppet-python/issues/64); Specify the source location (again):

```
file { '/tmp/foo/installer/requirements.txt':
  source  => 'puppet:///modules/foo/foo/installer/requirements.txt',
  ...
}
```

Another way is to specify a different filename which is not included in the first recursive copy, and use that for other dependencies:

```
file { '/tmp/foo/installer/requirements.tmp.txt':
  source  => '/tmp/foo/installer/requirements.txt',
  ...
}

python::virtualenv { '/tmp/python-virtualenv':
  requirements => '/tmp/foo/installer/requirements.tmp.txt',
```

This could also be implemented as a definition which wraps around python::virtualenv in this case.